# Why does margin-top work with inline-block but not with inline?

Tags: html, css

In the code below, I am trying to get the h1 element to have a top-margin. When I set the position to inline in the css, the margin-top doesn't show up. But when I change it to inline-block, it does. I am wondering if somebody can explain why this is the case. Thanks.

EDIT: Here's the code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pjPdE/

Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head> 
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MyFirstWebsite.css"> 
     <title> 
       Max Pleaner's First Website
     </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to my site.</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS

```
body {
    background-image:url('sharks.jpg');
    }

h1 {
    background-color:#1C0245;
    display:inline;
    padding: 6.5px 7.6px;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Section 9.2.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display) of the CSS2 specification states:

> **inline-block**
>   This value causes an element to generate an **inline-level block container**. The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.
>
> **inline**
>   This value causes an element to generate one or more inline boxes.

Further on in the CSS2 specification ([section 9.4.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting)) we get told that inline elements only respect horizontal margins ([proof](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/nRmq2/)):

> In an inline formatting context, boxes are laid out horizontally, one after the other, beginning at the top of a containing block. Horizontal margins, borders, and padding are respected between these boxes.

The difference between `inline` and `inline-block` is that `inline` elements are treated as inline whereas `inline-block` elements are effectively treated as blocks (which are visually inline with each other).

Block-level elements respect both horizontal and vertical margins whereas inline-level elements only respect horizontal margins.

Answer (score 5):

The `<h1>` tag is by default a *block element* which allows margins. Using `display: inline` turns it into an inline element such as a span tag which does not allow margins.

Using `display: inline-block` allows you to use both features of both elements.

> Displays an element as an inline-level block container. The inside of
>   this block is formatted as block-level box, and the element itself is
>   formatted as an inline-level box

Reference : [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Only block level elements can have margins.
giving it 'display: inline; forces it (unsurprisingly) to become an *inline* element, thus losing it's margin.

Try using inline-block if you want to keep it *inline* with other content and take advantage of margins . . .