# My margin-top its not working

Tags: css

Im trying to give some margin-top to my `.links li a`, but its not working, I give this margin but the links stay also without margin.

Do you see why this can be happening?

Here I have my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/dG6wn/2/

My html:

```
<div id="content">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <span id="date">22/05/2014</span> <br /> 
    <img class="img" src="../image1.jpg"/>
    <p>
        Paragraph text     
    </p>
    <div id="downloads">
        <h3>Links:</h3>
        <ul class="links">
            <li><a href="">Link bigger</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="back">Back</span>
</div>
```

My css:

```
.links li a 
{
    text-decoration:none;
    background:red;
    color:#000;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin:0 auto; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

```
position: relative;
display: inline-block; /* might need this too */
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked only with display:inline-block! But can you explain, if it is possible why we nedd this display:inline-block? Because Im not seeing why!

Comment: @Marby see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19153771/3041194

Answer (score 1):

reorder the margin styles. set display to inline-block.

```
.links li a 
{
    text-decoration:none;
    background:red;
    color:#000;
    margin:0 auto; 
    margin-top:20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

updated http://jsfiddle.net/dG6wn/3/