# How to position text in a div?

Tags: html, css, text, position

I am a little confused about how to position text in a `div`. I want the text to be in the centre  of the `div` **height-wise**, so I've tried changing the top `padding` and `margin` and also the position but nothing is working. This usually worked for me before so I don't know why it is not working now.
Here is the code I have

```
<div class="foot">
    <div class="menu">English</div>
    <div class="menu">Maths</div>
    <div class="menu">Science</div>
    <div class="menu">SAM</div>
    <div class="menu">German</div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.menu {
    width: 200px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px 7% 0% 7%;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative; 
}
.foot {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #54a992;
    border-top: solid black 1px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertical padding and margin [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19153573/1841194) with `inline` display, For your purpose in my opinion `inline-block` display could be okay:

```
.menu{
    margin-top: 25%;  /* Adjust it as you wish */
    width: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k2ypkto0/)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
.menu {
    line-height: 40px; /* add this */
    padding: 0 7%; /* changed this */
}
```

Your footer wrapper has a height of 40px. So by using the line-height 40px on the inner elements it will cause the text to be in the middle of the 40px.

Comment: ok thanks :) also it worked the same with and without the padding changed

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu{
    width: 200px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 7%;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: relative;

}
.foot{
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    line-height:40px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: #54a992;
    border-top: solid black 1px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0px;
}
```