# Can each of the LIs in a UL be animated separately?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to get each of the `li`s in an `ul` to slide up while fading in at the same time, but I just can't get the sliding up part to work, but the fadeIn part is working fine.

EDIT- Positive margin works with `inline-block`, but negative margin doesn't work.

https://jsfiddle.net/2txtxyu8/4/

HTML:

```
<ul>
        <li id="t">Home</li>
        <li id="r">About</li>
        <li id="e">Profile</li>
        <li id="w">Sign In</li>
        <li id="q">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {    
display: inline;
padding: 7px;
margin-top: 20px;
opacity: 0;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#q')
.animate({marginTop: '+=20', opacity: 1}, 600);
$('#w')
.delay(300)
.animate({marginTop: '+=20', opacity: 1}, 600);
```

Comment: please elaborate "a certain animation". What is your expected outcome?

Comment: sliding up + fadeIn at the same time... i thought it would be obvious from the code, still I've updated the question

Comment: Well if you want it to slide up in stead of down, you should use negative margin in stead of positive. Also make the list item an inline-block or else the margin won't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `display: inline-block;` on the list item

http://jsfiddle.net/fjtjwfqt/2/

Comment: yeah thanks, it worked. can you explain how inline-block made it to work?

Comment: @Jeevan The answer to this question gives a decent explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153573/why-does-margin-top-work-with-inline-block-but-not-with-inline

Comment: but when i use negative margin it doesn't work all of a sudden!! https://jsfiddle.net/2txtxyu8/4/

Comment: @Jeevan This is because the other list items still have the margin-top of 20px. The elements adjust to this margin because of the display property `inline`. If you wish to use different margin-top for each list items (including the ones that are set to 0 opacity) use floats in stead of display inline to align then next to each other. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/2txtxyu8/9/