# How align horizontally images inside link?

Tags: html, css

I have a start rating that i would like to align image starts horizontally

*i've tried without success!*

```css
img#rating_line {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: right;
}
#rating_line {
  height: 16px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
#rating_line a {
  height: 16px;
  display: inline;
  width: 400px
}
```

```html
<div id="rating_line">
  <a href="/products/7/">
    <div class="feedback_stars_rating">
      <img src="/star-off.png">
      <img src="/star-off.png">
      <img src="/star-off.png">
    </div>
  </a>
<div>
```

Comment: these would show the images inline, so you're either setting the width of the body or a parent element to something smaller that won't make them fit in one line, or some other CSS code is "overriding" your inline rules...

Comment: Alternate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153573/why-does-margin-top-work-with-inline-block-but-not-with-inline