# After I keep <li> elements on single line in fixed width <ul>, how can I move the icon before link?

Tags: html, css, icons

After I keep `li` elements on the single line in fixed width `<ul>`, how can I move the icon before links?

```css
.KK1 {
  width: 250px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.KK1 > li {
  display: table-cell;
}
.KK1 > li > a {
  display: block;
}
.icon-user {}
```

```html
<ul class="KK1">
  <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user">link</i></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-user">link</i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And my `.icon-user` just can adjust `margin-left` and `margin-right`, can't adjust `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, because `<i>` elements are not [block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/block-level_elements) but [inline-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)

Solution: Your `<li>` elements are block-level, you might want to put `class='icon-user'` there.

See also:

- [Why does margin-top work with inline-block but not with inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153573/why-does-margin-top-work-with-inline-block-but-not-with-inline)

Answer (score 0):

try using `display: inline-block;`

```
.icon-user{
   display: inline-block
   /* plus your styles */
}
```