# Animate Bootstrap Card Title Content

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website that uses Bootstrap 4. In this website, I'm using cards. Each card has a title. In the right hand side are some icons.

When a user clicks an icon, I want to cover the title with some specific content. I want to animate the content like the language stats bar on GitHub.

At this time, as shown in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tL4mjd5t/), I have the following:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9">
          Card Title      
          <div id="headerContent" class="d-none">
            This is content I want to animate in from the top.        
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
          <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o fa-lg float-right" onclick="toggleHeaderContent()"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

   <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h4>
      <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to make the `headerContent` animate like the language stats bar on GitHub. How do I do that animation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your code. Firstly, you are looking for a way to animate the `display` property from `display: inline` (Bootstrap 4 class `d-inline`) to `display: none` (Bootstrap class `d-none`), but [**the display property cannot be animated**](https://www.impressivewebs.com/animate-display-block-none/).

Of course, you could use a combination of `opacity` and `visibility` properties (as in my proposed solution below) to animate showing/hiding your header content,  but then you come to your other issue. You want to animate the title to appear from the top but [**inline elements are not transformable elements**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14883250/css-transform-doesnt-work-on-inline-elements), so you cannot animate them horizontally with `transform: translateY()`, but also [**they do not respect vertical margins**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153573/why-does-margin-top-work-with-inline-block-but-not-with-inline), so you cannot vertically animate them with `margin-top`.

What you can do is to use your own classes and animate its visibility (fade in). You could also make it appear from the left or right (but not from the top).

```
#headerContent {
  display: inline;  
}

.is-hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
}

.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9m3ft9ne/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out by update your css

```css
.your-title{position:relative;animation:animatetop 0.4s}@keyframes animatetop{from{top:-300px;opacity:0} to{top:0;opacity:1}}
```